# Understanding the use of generics in java

Tags: java, generics

Im trying to understand how class generics work and this bit just doesnt make sense to me.

So for instance if I have the following classes:

```
class A<E> {
    void go (E e) { } 
}

class B extends A { }
```

and then I try

```
A<? extends A> a1 = new A<A>();
A<? extends A> a2 = new A<B>();

a1.go(new A()); // i get a compiler error
a2.go(new B()); // i get a compiler error
```

Shouldn't the go method accept A or any sub class of A??

thanks :)

Comment: Not sure why people downvoted this.  While not the most well written question I've seen all day, its fair to ask.

Comment: ive updated the question with cleaner code..

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been answered before. The basic problem is that the construct `? extends A` doesn't mean "any type that extends from A"; it means "a specific, but *unknown* type, that extends from A". Without this restriction you could do `A<? extends Object> a = new A<String>(); a.go(new Object());`, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Think of it this way, OP: `a2.go(new A())` should _fail_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reasons for this are based on how Java implements generics.

**An Arrays Example**

With arrays you can do this (arrays are covariant as others have explained)

```
Integer[] myInts = {1,2,3,4};
Number[] myNumber = myInts;
```

But, what would happen if you try to do this?

```
Number[0] = 3.14; //attempt of heap pollution
```

This last line would compile just fine, but if you run this code, you could get an `ArrayStoreException`. Because you’re trying to put a double into an integer array (regardless of being accessed through a number reference).

This means that you can fool the compiler, but you cannot fool the runtime type system. And this is so because arrays are what we call *reifiable types*. This means that at runtime Java knows that this array was actually instantiated as an array of integers which simply happens to be accessed through a reference of type `Number[]`.

So, as you can see, one thing is the actual type of the object, an another thing is the type of the reference that you use to access it, right?

**The Problem with Java Generics**

Now, the problem with Java generic types is that the type information is discarded by the compiler and it is not available at run time. This process is called [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6). There are good reason for implementing generics like this in Java, but that's a long story, and it has to do with binary compatibility with pre-existing code.

But the important point here is that since, at runtime there is no type information, there is no way to ensure that we are not committing heap pollution.

For instance,

```
List<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myInts.add(1);
myInts.add(2);

List<Number> myNums = myInts; //compiler error
myNums.add(3.14); //heap polution
```

If the Java compiler does not stop you from doing this, the runtime type system cannot stop you either, because there is no way, at runtime, to determine that this list was supposed to be a list of integers only. The Java runtime would let you put whatever you want into this list, when it should only contain integers, because when it was created, it was declared as a list of integers.

As such, the designers of Java made sure that you cannot fool the compiler. If you cannot fool the compiler (as we can do with arrays) you cannot fool the runtime type system either.

As such, we say that generic types are *non-reifiable*.

Evidently, this would hamper polymorphism. Consider the following example:

```
static long sum(Number[] numbers) {
   long summation = 0;
   for(Number number : numbers) {
      summation += number.longValue();
   }
   return summation;
}
```

Now you could use it like this:

```
Integer[] myInts = {1,2,3,4,5};
Long[] myLongs = {1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L};
Double[] myDoubles = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

System.out.println(sum(myInts));
System.out.println(sum(myLongs));
System.out.println(sum(myDoubles));
```

But if you attempt to implement the same code with generic collections, you will not succeed:

```
static long sum(List<Number> numbers) {
   long summation = 0;
   for(Number number : numbers) {
      summation += number.longValue();
   }
   return summation;
}
```

You would get compiler erros if you try to...

```
List<Integer> myInts = asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Long> myLongs = asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L);
List<Double> myDoubles = asList(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0);

System.out.println(sum(myInts)); //compiler error
System.out.println(sum(myLongs)); //compiler error
System.out.println(sum(myDoubles)); //compiler error
```

The solution is to learn to use two powerful features of Java generics known as covariance and contravariance.

**Covariance**

With covariance you can read items from a structure, but you cannot write anything into it. All these are valid declarations.

```
List<? extends Number> myNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> myNums = new ArrayList<Float>()
List<? extends Number> myNums = new ArrayList<Double>()
```

And you can read from `myNums`:

```
Number n = myNums.get(0);
```

Because you can be sure that whatever the actual list contains, it can be upcasted to a Number (after all anything that extends Number is a Number, right?)

However, you are not allowed to put anything into a covariant structure.

```
myNumst.add(45L); //compiler error
```

This would not be allowed, because Java cannot guarantee what is the actual type of the object in the generic structure. It can be anything that extends Number, but the compiler cannot be sure. So you can read, but not write.

**Contravariance**

With contravariance you can do the opposite. You can put things into a generic structure, but you cannot read out from it.

```
List<Object> myObjs = new List<Object();
myObjs.add("Luke");
myObjs.add("Obi-wan");

List<? super Number> myNums = myObjs;
myNums.add(10);
myNums.add(3.14);
```

In this case, the actual nature of the object is a List of Objects, and through contravariance, you can put Numbers into it, basically because all numbers have Object as their common ancestor. As such, all Numbers are objects, and therefore this is valid.

However, you cannot safely read anything from this contravariant structure assuming that you will get a number.

```
Number myNum = myNums.get(0); //compiler-error
```

As you can see, if the compiler allowed you to write this line, you would get a ClassCastException at runtime.

**Get/Put Principle**

As such, use covariance when you only intend to take generic values out of a structure, use contravariance when you only intend to put generic values into a structure and use the exact generic type when you intend to do both.

The best example I have is the following that copies any kind of numbers from one list into another list. It only *gets* items from the source, and it only *puts* items in the destiny.

```
public static void copy(List<? extends Number> source, List<? super Number> destiny) {
    for(Number number : source) {
        destiny.add(number);
    }
}
```

Thanks to the powers of covariance and contravariance this works for a case like this:

```
List<Integer> myInts = asList(1,2,3,4);
List<Integer> myDoubles = asList(3.14, 6.28);
List<Object> myObjs = new ArrayList<Object>();

copy(myInts, myObjs);
copy(myDoubles, myObjs);
```

Comment: Just 5 votes? This needs more! If it were by Jon Skeet it would have 100x :P

Answer (score 3):

When you declare

```
A<? extends A> a1 = new A<A>();
```

the compiler knows only that `a1`'s type parameter is `A` or some subclass thereof--it doesn't know which one.

If you change it to `A<A> a1`, then it will know that an instance of `A` is a legal argument. The same applies for `a2`.

On a related note, the line

```
class B extends A
```

uses a raw type. You should instead say `Class B extends A<SomeType>` or `Class B<E> extends A<E>`.

Comment: but when I intialize it with new A<A> on right hand side shouldnt it know its type A

Why does it work with the constructor
`public class Test <E>{`
`public Test(E e){}`
`Test<? extends A> a1 = new Test<A>(new A());`
`Test<? extends A> a2 = new Test<B>(new B());}`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is: The method go(capture#1-of ? extends A) in the type A is not applicable for the arguments (A)

The reason for it: You are not specific about reference a1. It is defined on a capture of "? extends A" that can never be duplicated. Again, when you create a new A() it passes another capture of the "? extends A", the A itself, that cannot be converted to the former.

Comment: so does it mean its not useful at all?? Why would it let u do that?

It doesnt work with arraylists either..

`ArrayList<? extends A> array = new ArrayList<B>();`
`array.add(new B()); //compiler Error`

Comment: It is only useful if you can fix this capture on something predefined by other means, as in this method: `public static int countArray(ArrayList<? extends A> array) { return array.size(); }` This way you can pass an ArrayList<B> to this method, but still can't add to the list. You are restricted to something like <? super B> here.