# Java generics inheritance cryptic error

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a receiver class that puts messages in a message queue as following

```
public class Receiver<T extends MessageBase> {

  private LinkedBlockingQueue<T> messageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>();

  public void add(T msg) {
    messageQueue.add(msg);
  }

  public void Class<T> getType() {
    ...
  }
}
```

When trying to add messages as this

```
public <T extends MessageBase> void processMessage(T msg) {
    for (Receiver<? extends MessageBase> r : receivers) {
        if (msg.getClass().equals(r.getType())) {
            r.add(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I get a

```
The method add(capture#3-of ? extends MessageBase) in the type 
Receiver<capture#3-of ? extends MessageBase> is not applicable 
for the arguments (T)
```

since the `Receiver` class is casted to extend `MessageBase` should it not work to add messages which are subclasses of `MessageBase`?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604477/use-of-extends-and-super-in-collection-generics/12605337#12605337). The best way to remember is the acronym PECS, Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`. A producer gives you data (e.g. through a `get` method), so producers use `extends`. What you want is a consumer which takes data (e.g. through an `add` method). See my explanation at that link for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use generic's with lowerbound (? extends Type syntax) you cannot add anything into your container.

```
for (Receiver<? extends MessageBase> r : receivers) {
        if (msg.getClass().equals(r.getType())) {
            r.add(msg);// This is wrong, as you cannot add anything into Receiver
        }
    }
```

Refer to this answer for [Why it isn't allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993745/add-strings-through-use-of-generic-extends-causes-compiler-error/13993770#13993770)

Answer (score 1):

Java does not know the actual parameter type of `add(T msg)` as it depends on `T`.

`r` is defined as `Receiver<? extends MessageBase>`, hence it is of an unknown type (albeit based on `MessageBase`).

So Java cannot match both as they might be of a different (non-matching) type. For example msg could have a `MessageBase1` type and `r` could have a `MessageBase2` type, which are (obviously) incompatible.