# Generic arraylist with wild card of object

Tags: java, generics

I have created a list like below.

```
ArrayList<? extends Object> arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

what i understand by above line this is an upper bounding any element which is subclass of object can be added to the list.
Now I am trying like this:

```
String str = new String("str");
Integer i = new Integer(4);
Object obj = new Object();
arr.add(obj);
arr.add(str);
arr.add(i);
```

They all are giving error.What is the problem here?
But when I change it to

```
ArrayList<? super Object> arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

All works.It is lower bounding. Can anyone explain it to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add anything into the collection **except null** when your collection uses wildcards with upperbounds as generic type. The reason is because you could just be adding a wrong time in your collection. For more explanation [**Refer This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993745/add-strings-through-use-of-generic-extends-causes-compiler-error/13993770#13993770)

Answer (score 0):

Declaration `ArrayList <? extends Object> arr` means that `arr` is an `ArrayList` with elements of some unknown type, and the only thing known about this unknown type is that it extends `Object`.  Once you don't know the type of `ArrayList` elements, the only value you can put there is `null`.  Putting any other value will result in error because compiler cannot verify that value you are putting into `ArrayList` is convertable to the (unknown) type of `ArrayList` elements.  Event the following code will be illegal:

```
arr.set (0, arr.get (0));
```

It is illegal because from compiler's point of view `arr.get (0)` will return value of some unknown type, that extends object, so it will threat this like `arr.set (0, (Object)arr.get (0))`.  But it cannot safely put value of type `Object` into `arr` because `arr` is not `ArrayList` of `Object`, but rather `ArrayList` or some unknown type that extends `Object`.  It may be `ArrayList` of `String` or `ArrayList` of Integer or whatever.

Comment: then why its working? 
    ArrayList<? super Object> arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
Here we also have unknown type.