# Why doesn't the following line compile?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, compiler-errors

I am trying to create an arraylist which can contain any type of object by using a generic with an unbounded wildcard.

```
ArrayList<?> params = new ArrayList<?>();
```

I do not understand why I receive the following error and I want to know where I am going wrong?

```
  required: class or interface without bounds
  found:    ?
```

Comment: Why not just `ArrayList<Object>`?

Comment: I know I can use ArrayList<Object> but I want to know how to use an unbounded generic.

Comment: A list *instance* never has a bounded type: a list is always a list with elements of a particular type. It is only list *variables* which can be bounded, in order to store lists of particular types within those bounds.

Comment: @Carcigenicate why not just `new ArrayList<>()`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I was referring to the type declaration. Yes, on the right you can use the diamond operator.

Comment: @Andy Turner isn't ArrayList<?> params = new ArrayList<>(); the same as ArrayList<?> params = new ArrayList<?>();  so if the former compiles why shouldn't the latter?

Comment: @coderboi27 the fact that one compiles and the other doesn't shows it is different.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to your problem is to use an `ArrayList<Object>`:

```
ArrayList<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();
```

The `?` operator refers to all objects **that are of unknown type**, so using it to add objects of known type (e.g. String) will cause errors, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810513/generic-arraylist-with-wild-card-of-object).

Comment: Don't use `Object` as generic parameter for collections. This is only marginally better than raw types.

Comment: @Turing85 how do you figure it is only marginally better than raw types? `Object` is no more or less valid than any other type: if you want to produce and consume elements of any type, `Object` is what you should use.

Comment: @AndyTurner You use generics for type safety. In most cases, `Object` is not what you want and you end up casting anyway. I am aware that OPs approach does not leave much room for anything else, but it suggests that there is a flaw somewhere in the system.

Comment: @Turing85 but a `List<Object>` is as valid a choice as any, if that is what you require. It is not like a raw type, because you can't pass a `List<Object>` to a method expecting a `List<Number>`, whereas you can pass a raw `List`.

Comment: @AndyTurner that is what I meant by "marginally better" =)

Answer (score 1):

You simply aren't allowed to do this. It says this in [JLS 15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9):

> If TypeArguments is present immediately after new, or immediately before (, then it is a compile-time error if any of the type arguments are wildcards (§4.5.1).

A list *instance* never has a bounded type: a list is always a list with elements of a particular type.

It is only list *variables* which can be bounded, in order to store lists with elements of particular types within those bounds.

So, this would be fine:

```
ArrayList<?> params = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
```

or

```
ArrayList<?> params = new ArrayList<>();
```

That's not to say that you can't use bounds on the RHS at all:

```
new ArrayList<List<?>>()
```

would be fine, because `List<?>` isn't a wildcard (because syntactically wildcards always start with `?`).

Answer (score 1):

You can’t write `new ArrayList<?>` because there’s no such thing as an `ArrayList<?>`.

Every ArrayList has a *specific type.*  When you write `ArrayList<?> params`, you are telling the compiler:  “This variable will hold an ArrayList whose elements are a specific type, like String or Number, but as I write this line of code, I don’t know what that type will be.”

So you can *refer* to an ArrayList as having a type that is not known at compile time, but every existing ArrayList has an actual type, regardless of how variables refer to it.  When code creates an ArrayList, that type has to be specified.