# Why can not I add an object of type Object into a List<?>?

Tags: java, generics

As far as I understand a  `List<?>` is definds as a *list of some specific , yet unknown type* . So whatever is the parameter type of this `List`, it should be extending `Object` because in Java you can not have any type that doesn't extend `Object`. So why the following code doesn't get compiled ? How is it violating the the invariant of the `listObj`

```
    List<?> listObj = returnSomeList();
    listObj.add(new Object()); //Why does this not work ?
```

Comment: Truth be told, the Oracle tutorials have a page dedicated to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html A couple of the below answers are *close* ... but the tutorial really explains it quite well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`List<?> listObj` can point to any type of List that can store different kind of objects.

How do you think, would it be safe to let it add any objects if for example

```
List<?> listObj = new ArrayList<String>();
listObj.add(new Object());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<?> and `List<? extends Object>` are identical.
```

you cannot add any thing into the collection which uses ? extends Type syntax(wildcards with subtype).The **reason** is that you could just be adding the wrong type into the collection.

### If it were allowed:

```
List<?> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
listOfObjects.add(new Object()); //not valid
somewhere in future

listOfObjects = new ArrayList<Animal>();
listOfObjects.add(new Animal());
```

If it were allowed you just added an Animal into Object list, which voilates the whole reason of generic types. when you retrieve the Animal from the collection, you'd have to again do the **instanceOf** check to see if its the Animal and cast it back to animal as we did in **pre-generics code.**

**[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993745/add-strings-through-use-of-generic-extends-causes-compiler-error/13993770#13993770)**

Comment: Do I understand you correct? Are you saying that the last line is not permitted, because `Animal` is a subtype of `Object`?

Comment: @jlordo nah, that's not what i meant. please check the reson in my edit ... :)

Comment: Sorry to say that but it's exactly the opposite: you can add an Animal into an Object list but you cannot add an Object to an Animal List; so your example is like kind of a socket that have been put in reverse.

Comment: @SylvainL i know that. my intention was if it were allowed to add sub-types when you use `? extends Type` syntax you could just be adding a wrong type into the collection .

Comment: @PremGenError: the problem with your example is if it were allowed, the first add(new Object()) should be considered valid and would be valid but a second one, set in the future after setting the list to an array of Animal, would still be considered valid by the compiler but now would be wrong. This is why I'm saying that you have kind of inverted it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Object` is the most generic type in Java. It doesn't qualify to be called as specific to any level.

Answer (score 0):

"?" is called **WildCard Capture** which means type parameter matches an Unknown Type. This means

```
 List<?> listObj = returnSomeList();
```

is a list of

```
 Unknown Type
```

and you are trying to add an **Object** into a List of

```
  Unknown Type.
```

The example posted by you will give you compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a confusion between a `List<Object>` and a `List<?>` or `List<? extends Object>`.

With a `List<Object>`, you can put anything into it but `List<?>` doesn't mean that this is a List or that it will (necessarily) receive a `List<Object>`.

It could receive a `List<Object>`, in this case adding an Object would be permissible; however, it could also receive anything else like a `List<Integer>`, a `List<String>` or a `List<Animal>`.  Obviously, you cannot add an Object to a `List<Integer>`, a `List<String>` or a `List<Animal>`.

As the compiler doesn't remember the type of the object between instructions, adding an Object will always be illegal even if you set the `List<?>` to a `List<Object>` because the compiler won't remember that you have set it to a `List<Object>`.