# Initialise Java List in Scala with Java ArrayList

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion

When being in scala and I write

```
val data: java.util.List[java.util.List[Double]] = new java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[Double]]()
```

I get the error

> Expression of type util.ArrayList[util.ArrayList[Double]] does not conform to expected type util.List[util.List[Double]]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess it's something like this `val data: java.util.List[java.util.List[Double]] = new java.util.ArrayList[java.util.List[Double]]()`

Comment: @JoachimHuet: Thanks! That worked. If you like you can turn that into an answer - maybe providing an explanation (otherwise people will comment, it has too little content). I will except it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use `val data: java.util.List[java.util.List[Double]] = new java.util.ArrayList[java.util.List[Double]]()`

Because generic types are not polymorphic in Java. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993745/add-strings-through-use-of-generic-extends-causes-compiler-error/13993770#13993770)

You could also have write the following in order to explicit the type :

`val data: java.util.List[? extends java.util.List[Double]] = new java.util.ArrayList[java.util.ArrayList[Double]]()`

To be easily understood `List<A>` is not a `super` of `List<B>` even if `B extends A`.

Comment: 1. Java generic types aren't polymorphic, Scala types can be. 2. The Scala syntax for the last type is `java.util.List[_ <: java.util.List[Double]]`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: With 2. I get errors later on, when passing `data` to methods that except `java.util.List[java.util.List[Double]]`: the method signature does not exist.

Comment: @Make42 To work with those methods, you need the first solution, they aren't equivalent. `java.util.List[_ <: java.util.List[Double]]` is a supertype of `java.util.List[java.util.List[Double]]`, so it's like passing `Object` to methods expecting `String`: you want to get errors!

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Sorry, for my slow understanding: What do you mean with "first solution"? Maybe you can write an answer and explain in smaller steps? I think this would also be helpful for readers in the future :-).

Comment: @Make42 The one in the first sentence: `val data: java.util.List[java.util.List[Double]] = new java.util.ArrayList[java.util.List[Double]]()`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer applies to Java but I guess that the reason is the same.

You are mixing polymorphism by subtype with generics. It's true that an `ArrayList<T>` can be assigned to a `List<T>` variable but here you have a `List<List<T>>` and you are trying to assign an object of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>`.

But a `List<E>` is not a subtype of `List<F>` even if F is a subtype of E so this is not allowed directly (invariance), but Scala has [tools](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#variance) to manage this issue (as Java has bounds and wildcards).