# Generic Java code difficult to understand?

Tags: java, generics

I found a [Java code line](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/10/java-features-applicability.html) that represents the Java generics functionality, but I am having trouble to read and understand it. How is the following Java code line to be understood?

`public <T, F> ContractValidator<T extends Contract> T validate(Validator<T>, F object)`

Comment: Reading some java tutorial/book etc. would be a good start...

Comment: And what exactly can't you understand?

Comment: How about start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the use of generics in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174371/understanding-the-use-of-generics-in-java)

Comment: There are errors in this line: there are two return types `ContractValidator<T extends Contract>` and `T` instead of one and the variable name for the argument of type `Validator<T>` is missing.

Comment: Ok, it was the broken part then that confused me! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I can appreciate some confusion from this:  the generics are ***broken***.  I don't mean broken as in, "they don't make sense to someone that knows generics"; I mean broken as in they don't *compile*.  So don't take what they're saying at literal face value; it'll only serve to confuse you more.

So let's start with the obvious.  Strip out all of the generics, and we're left with perceived raw types.

```
public ContractValidator validate(Validator, Object object)
```

I removed the ambiguous double-return since it doesn't make much sense. I'd also presume they want a variable for that first argument...

```
public ContractValidator validate(Validator validator, Object object) {
    return null;
}
```

So what we've got is some `Validator` and some `Object` going into this `validate` method, and what we get out of it is a `ContractValidator`.

That's awesome, except we can validate anything (theoretically).  What if our `Validator` were type-bound to a specific thing to validate?

```
public <T extends Contract> ContractValidator validate(Validator<T> validator, Object object) {
    return null;
}
```

The expression `<T extends Contract>` turns it into a **bound generic.**  More specifically, it's an [upper bound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html); any `Validator` types that are not typed with either `Contract` or `____ extends Contract` will not work in this.

Okay, so now we're getting somewhere - we have some validator that is explicitly bound to look only at something that either is or is a child of a `Contract`.  Shouldn't our `ContractValidator` return a result that contains something like that?

```
public <T extends Contract> ContractValidator<T> validate(Validator<T> validator, Object object) {
    return null;
}
```

Now this is where I disagree with the design.  The intent that they're going for (for some reason) is to have an *unbound* generic type; presumably to allow you to validate against anything.  But I don't know what purpose the type serves - it literally can be anything.

It's accomplished by writing:

```
public <T extends Contract, F> ContractValidator<T> validate(Validator<T> validator, F object) {
    return null;
}
```

---

Now, I've written all of this to effectively show that generics *are* understandable, provided that the examples you're shown can reasonably compile and make some semantic sense.  For the most part, if you were to use generics, you'd be doing so because you're trying to either create some polymorphic method, or you're trying to create a polymorphic container.

[Here's a great resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) on generics; the Java Trails have never steered me wrong on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very extensive and absolutely fantastic 100% answer. I actually have no questions as you gave helpful links! +10 for you!

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph where you took this line of code explains that using generics too much can make your code complicated. The intent of this line is to show how hard it can be to understand.

Anyway it's not meant to be a good example of generics, and actually I don't think that it's correct.