# Java type inference of a parametrized type such as List

Tags: java

While coding this morning, I found something that was odd to me and I would like an explanation of why java acts like this.
Here's a snippet that explain what I was doing :

```
public class Test{

  static int method(List<CharSequence> a) {
    //nothing important here
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("abc", "def");
    //this won't compile since it expect a list of CharSequence
    method(myList);
  }

}
```

I would have expected this to compile since a String implements a CharSequence.
I know I can change the signature of method in order to have :

```
static int method(List<? extends CharSequence> a)
```

Is it a way in Java to be able to force the type of object in my List to stricly be a CharSequence ?

Thanks for your answers !

Edit : 
As said by @sweeper this is a duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)
Thanks for all your answers, that's something I knew but completely forgot.

Comment: *"Is it a way in Java to be able to force the type of object in my List to stricly be a CharSequence ?"* `CharSequence` is an interface; you cannot have an object which is "strictly" a `CharSequence` and not some subtype of it.

Comment: Are you looking for `List<CharSequence> myList = Arrays.asList("abc", "def");`?

Comment: @Sweeper yes I could make this work declaring my list this way.

I was just trying to make my example as simple as possible. I just want an explanation as to why java forbids to do what I wrote.

Comment: You may want to read this other answer to [Understanding the use of generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11174536/697630). This is a old,  popular and very repetitive question.

Comment: A `StringBuilder` is a `CharSequence`, what do you expect to happen when you call `a.add(new StringBuilder())`?

Comment: @Sweeper - it won't allow you to do `a.add("Hello");` inside the body of the method.

Comment: Why is that relevant? It is a fact that you can't mutate a list created with `Arrays.asList`, but this question is about generics. @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: This is called invariance of generics. [Read here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant).